# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "EQ"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to join 3 tables to get data but with following query I've got an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EQ"`

query

```
Process.joins(process_template: :process_groups).where("process_groups IS EQ COMPANY_DATA")
```

Models explanations

```
model Process
belongs_to :process_template

model ProcessTemplate
has_many :process_groups

model ProcessGroup
belongs_to :process_template
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo? `COMAPNY_DATA` should be `COMPANY_DATA`?

Comment: Nope, this is my typo, updated

Comment: @mr_muscle Is your problem solved?

Comment: @demir nope, it's related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557539/database-query-for-dynamic-search-with-activerecord-or-pure-sql-activerecordas

Answer (score 1):

Try it with rails way:

```
Process.joins(process_template: :process_groups)
       .where(process_groups: { column_name_in_process_groups_table: COMPANY_DATA })
```