# Database query for dynamic search with ActiveRecord or pure SQL ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my db I don't have column `company_name` but I have records that `inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' }` and under their value I will get string with company name.

To get one company name I have to do:

```
first_process = Process.first
                .inquiry_field_responses
                .joins(:inquiry_field)
                .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
```

which returns ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation so I have to do:

```
first_process.first&.value
```

And I will get string with company name

```
  InquiryFieldResponse Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "inquiry_field_responses".* FROM "inquiry_field_responses" INNER JOIN "inquiry_fields" ON "inquiry_fields"."id" = "inquiry_field_responses"."inquiry_field_id" WHERE "inquiry_field_responses"."inquiry_process_id" = $1 AND "inquiry_fields"."name" = $2 ORDER BY "inquiry_field_responses"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["inquiry_process_id", 55], ["name", "company_name"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "bbbbb"
```

Based on that how to find all Processes with company name ie. 'aaa' ?
From what I understand, I have to create query like

```
Process.joins(process_field_responses, process_field)
       .where(process field name is equal company name and value is equal to aaa)
```

So I was trying with:

```
Process.joins(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field)
       .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
       .where("value LIKE ?", "aaa")
```

but I've got an errror:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "value" does not exist)

and it's true, this column doesn't exist.

Is it possible to create such a query?

[EDIT] inquiry_field_responses columns table

```
  create_table "inquiry_field_responses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "encrypted_value"
    t.bigint "inquiry_process_id"
    t.bigint "inquiry_field_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "custom_flow_model_id"
    t.string "encrypted_value_iv"
```

Comment: You first need to know where the value is saved. I'm guessing somewhere in the `inquiry_field_responses` table. What columns does that table have?

Comment: @3limin4t0r thanks for your response! but isn't the value just post-processing from ruby side? table columns in edited post